# Find a synthetic solution: $T(24^{\circ}, 26^{\circ}, 28^{\circ}, 10^{\circ}, 22^{\circ})$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Figure:
[image: figure 1]
My try:
Let $O$ be the circumcircle center of triangle $BDC$. When angles are placed $\angle{OBC}=36^{\circ}.$ Let's use this to construct the regular pentagon $BOCFG$ on $[BO]$. Somehow, $\angle{ABG}=\angle{DAC}$ . I couldn't move forward from here. Any help will be appreciated.
[image: figure 2]

Comment: I think it is not about pentagon. Consider $T(24,26,22,10,28)$. There $26+22=48\neq 54$. Consider $T(28,16,30,14,16)$. There $16+30=46$. We can interchange angles $22$ and $28$ in this construction without changing 3 other angles.

Comment: A case of "Langley's adventitious angles" ; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible with only compass and straight edge, unless I am missing something.

Are you given anything to start with or should you construct the topmost figure without any given auxiliary data? If you may use next to compass and straight edge other resources please be explicit about it.

Why is it impossible with only ruler and straight edge? If it was possible you can construct angles $2^{\circ}=26^{\circ}-24^{\circ}$ and $178^{\circ}=180^{\circ}-2^{\circ}$. With an angle of $178^{\circ}$ you could construct a regular $180$-gon. This is however not possible according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction#Constructing_regular_polygons): $180$ is not in the list of constructible regular $n$-gons. The details of a proof for this impossibility usually involve algebraic number theory and in particular Galois theory, i.e. require university level math.

I hope this answers your question, if not, please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you for your alert. The question is given as above, we can solve such langley problems using trigonometric answer. My question, what I mean by synthetic solution, is whether there is a solution other than the trigonometric answer. So you can use all the elements of the geometry. I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: I am confused about your question. You are given the 4 point configuration as in the top image. You seem to know already that the angle marked with a "?" has measure $22^{\circ}$. What exactly do you want if not a compass and straightedge construction of the configuration from scratch? What exactly are "all the elements of the geometry"? E.g. are you allowed to put markings on a ruler as in [this construction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction)?

Comment: I understand. I'm looking for a geometric solution to a problem that I can solve with trigonometry. You can check out my other $T(12^{\circ}, 24^{\circ}, 54^{\circ}, 18^{\circ}, 30^{\circ})$ question, there was an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENPwk.jpg)
$\text{Let }P\text{ and }Q\text{ be the circumcenters of the }\triangle ABC\text{ and }\triangle BCD\text{ respectively, then }PQ⟂BC.\\
\text{Let }R\text{ be the circumcenter of the }\triangle BPQ.\\
\text{Reflect }\triangle BRP\text{ in }BP\text{ and rotate around }P\text{ to }\triangle ASP.\\
\text{Reflect }\triangle BRQ\text{ in }BQ\text{ and rotate around }Q\text{ to }\triangle DTQ.\\
∴\;AS=SP=PR=BR=RQ=QT=TD\\
∵\;∠BQC=∠BQD+∠DQC=2∠BCD+2∠DBC=108°\\
\begin{align}
∴\;&∠BRP=2∠BQP=2·\frac{1}{2}∠BQC=108° \text{, i.e. }∠ASP=108°\\
\end{align}$
$\text{Construct a regular pentagon }ASPFE\text{ and a equilateral triangle }AEG.\\$
$\begin{align}
∵\;&∠APB=2∠ACB=76°\\
&∠APG=\frac{1}{2}∠APE=\frac{1}{2}∠AFE=\frac{1}{2}·\frac{180°−∠AEF}{2}=18°\\
&∠BPR=\frac{180°−∠BRP}{2}=36°\\
∴\;&∠GPR=∠APB−∠APG+∠BPR=94°\\
∵\;&∠BPC=∠APB+∠APC=2∠ACB+2∠ABC=176°\\
∴\;&∠CBP=\frac{180°−∠BPC}{2}=2°\\
∵\;&∠CBQ=\frac{180°−∠BQC}{2}=36°\\
∴\;&∠PBQ=∠CBQ−∠CBP=34°\\
∵\;&∠PRQ=2∠PBQ=68°\\
∴\;&∠BRQ=∠BRP+∠PRQ=176°\\
∴\;&∠BQR=\frac{180°−∠BRQ}{2}=2° \text{, i.e. }∠DQT=2°\\
∵\;&∠BQD=2∠BCD=56°\\
∴\;&∠RQT=∠BQR+∠BQD+∠DQT=60°\\
\end{align}\\$
$\text{Thus, }\triangle RQT \text{ is a equilateral triangle.}$

$\begin{align}
∴\;&RP=RT, ∠RTQ=60°\\
∵\;&∠PRT=∠PRQ−∠TRQ=8°\\
∴\;&∠RTP=∠RPT=\frac{180°−∠PRT}{2}=86°\\
∴\;&∠GPR+∠RPT=180°\\
\end{align}\\
\text{Therefore, the three points }G, P, T\text{ are collinear.}$

$\begin{align}
∵\;&∠DTQ=∠BRQ=176°\\
∴\;&∠DTP=∠DTQ−∠RTP−∠RTQ=30°\\
∵\;&∠AGP=\frac{360°−∠AGE}{2}=150°\\
∴\;&∠AGT+∠DTG=∠AGP+∠DTP=180°\\
∴\;&AG/\!/DT\\
\end{align}\\
\text{Hence, }ADTG\text{ is a parallelogram.}$

$\begin{align}
∴\;&AD /\!/ GT\\
∴\;&∠DAP=∠APG=18°\\
∵\;&∠BAP=\frac{180°−∠APB}{2}=52°\\
∴\;&∠BAD=∠BAP+∠DAP=70°\\
\end{align}$