# Compute Angle X! From a Japanese magazine.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

So, pretty straight forward. In the following figure, find the measure of $\angle X$.

I have in fact solved it, using a somewhat complicated but acceptable synthetic solution. I'm curious to see what other solutions there could be.

Edit: Posted my solution below:

[image]

Comment: You should edit in your method. Otherwise: (1) we don’t know what your “synthetic” solution is and can’t provide “_other_” solutions unless you tell us your method. (2) It is disheartening to put in time and effort to illustrate, type the mathjax for, and post the answer, only to be told by the OP “yeah, that’s what I did. I was looking for something else. “

Comment: You're right, I'll type up my answer as soon as a I reach home and post it here. Hard to write all the MathJax notation on a mobile device

Comment: There is not always beautiful solution of such problems. This problem is $T(27,3,6,81,33)$ in terms of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512979/find-a-synthetic-solution-t24-circ-26-circ-28-circ-10-circ-22.

Comment: I do agree, my solution isn't exactly the prettiest but it is indeed possible. I'll post it here soon.

Comment: A case of "Langley's adventitious angles" ; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles)

Comment: Please give the full reference (in particular the issue number) of the magazine, even if few people will have a look at it... It can be very useful for tracking.

Comment: I have not been able to locate exactly which magazine it is from, but I have been able to find out that it's from the year 1993. In any case, I have posted my own approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Law of Sines: $\sin(63-x)\sin(81)\sin(3)=\sin(27)\sin(x)\sin6$.

Now we claim $x=33$.

Let $f=e^i$. Then the above equation give
$$(f^{30}-f^{-30})(f^{81}-f^{-81})(f^{3}-f^{-3})=(f^{27}-f^{-27})(f^{33}-f^{-33})(f^{3}-f^{-3})$$
and gives
$$f^{114}-f^{108}-f^{-48}+f^{-54}-f^{54}+f^{48}+f^{-108}-f^{-114}=f^{66}-f^{54}+f^{-12}-f^{12}+f^{-54}-f^{-66}.$$
Using $-f^{-x}=f^{180-x}$, we have further simplification,
$$-f^{108}-f^{-48}+f^{48}+f^{-108}=f^{-12}-f^{12}.$$
This is just $\sin108-\sin48=\sin12$ which is easily true.

Answer (score 8):

So, this'll be my own answer for those that wanted to see it. I'll add a brief explanation below as well.

[image: Click Here]

As for the solution, here's how it goes:

1.) Name the triangle $ABC$, with point O inside. $\angle A = 63$, $\angle B = 30$ and $\angle C = 87$.

2.) Locate point $D$ outside $\triangle ABC$ and connect it with point $O$ such that $CD=CO$ and $\angle COD$ = $\angle CDO = 3$. Note that $\angle OBC = 3$, therefore line $OD=OB$

3.) Locate another point $E$ outside $\triangle ABC$ and connect it to point O such that $\angle OEA = \angle OBA = 27$, therefore line $OB=OE=OD$. (Note: Some people may wonder why point E must lie outside of the triangle and not inside or over point A, this can easily be proven via contradiction. If needed, leave a comment on this answer and I shall attach that prove as well).

4.) Notice that $\angle EOD = 60$, with $OE=OD$, connect point $E$ with $D$, therefore $OB=OE=OD=ED$. Connect point $E$ with $C$. Note that $\angle EOC = \angle EDC = 63$. Also note that $OC=CD$ and $OE=ED$, this implies that $\triangle EOC$ and $\triangle EDC$ are congruent via the SAS property. This further implies that $\angle ECO = \angle ECD = 87$. Thus, $\angle ACE=87-81=6$.

5.) Notice that $\angle AED$ is supplementary to $\angle ACD$ $(87+93=180)$. This further implies that $\angle CAE$ and $\angle CDE$ must also be supplementary. This proves that Quadrilateral $AEDC$ is in fact cyclic.

6.) Above implies that $\angle ACE = \angle ADE = 6$ via the property of cyclic quadrilaterals. Notice that $\triangle ADE$ has $\angle AED = 87$, and $\angle ADE = 6$. This implies that $\angle EAD =87$ as well $(87+87+6=180)$. This proves that $\triangle ADE$ is isosceles where $ED=AD=OD=OE$.

7.) Above implies that point $D$ is the circumcenter for $\triangle OAE$, therefore $\angle AOE$ is exactly half of $\angle ADE = 3$. This means that $\angle OAB = 27+3=30$. Hence, $\angle X = 63-30=33$.

Comment: Nice solution. Your proof can be adapted to a more general problem: if $\angle OBA=30^\circ - t, \angle CBO=t, \angle OCB=2t, \angle ACO=90^\circ-3t$ then $\angle OAC=30^\circ+t$.

Comment: I see, that's interesting, I'll look into that. And thank you!

Comment: You always need an eqileteral triangle. @Goku Why?

Comment: @BobDobbs My answer in this post might help explain my motivation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552723/to-find-angles-of-a-quadrilateral/4553728#4553728