# Determine the length of a side of a quadrilateral given constraints on its angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Assume the length of $|AB|$ and the following angles are known:
$\measuredangle ABD$,$\measuredangle DBC$,$\measuredangle DAC$.
Assume it is also known that $\measuredangle ADC=\measuredangle DCA$ (not in the attached figure).

What is the length of $|AD|$? (I guess there may be multiple, countable  solutions).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the cosine rule to triangles $DAC$, $DBC$, $ABD$ and $ABC$: you'll get four equations in the four unknowns $AC=AD$, $BD$, $BC$, $CD$.

Eliminating $AC$ and $CD$ is easy: one is left with two quadratic equations in $BC$ and $BD$, having in general four solutions (possibly complex).

I used Mathematica to get an explicit solution but it's too long to be of any use. It's probably wiser to get a numerical solution through some routine.